# Duplicado de inserciones

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

Realizando un sistema de contratos me encuentro con inconveniente que no he podido resolver, pues intentando crear un select y mediante javascript genere otro select correspondiente al dato solicitado en el primero, me genera un duplicado de inserciones, a continuación detallaré las tablas y las vistas creadas para hacer las consultas:

```
CREATE TABLE ciclos_escolares(
id_ciclo integer NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id_ciclo));

CREATE TABLE dependencias(
clave_depe integer NOT NULL,
depe_ciclo integer NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (clave_depe, depe_ciclo),

CONSTRAINT fk_dependencia_ciclo FOREIGN KEY (depe_ciclo) REFERENCES ciclos_escolares (id_ciclo));

CREATE TABLE evaluados(
plaza_eva integer NOT NULL,
eva_depe integer NOT NULL,
eva_ciclo integer NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(plaza_eva, eva_depe, eva_ciclo),

CONSTRAINT fk_evaluado_dependencia FOREIGN KEY (eva_ciclo, eva_depe) REFERENCES dependencias (depe_ciclo, clave_depe));
```

CREACION DE LAS VISTAS PARA HACER LAS CONSULTAS

```
CREATE VIEW view_dependencia_cicloesc as
SELECT * FROM dependencias 
INNER JOIN ciclos_escolares
on dependencias.depe_ciclo = ciclos_escolares.id_ciclo;

CREATE VIEW view_evaluados_dependencias as
SELECT * FROM evaluados
INNER JOIN dependencias
ON evaluados.eva_depe = dependencias.clave_depe;
```

A continuación se detalla el fragmento de código realizado con HTML
seccion/evaluados.php

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col form-group">
                            <label for="eva_ciclo">Ciclo escolar</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="eva_ciclo" id="eva_ciclo">
                                <option value="0">--Elige ciclo escolar--</option>
                                <option value="20221">CICLO ESCOLAR 1 ENERO AL 31 DE JULIO 2021</option>
                                <option value="20222">CICLO ESCOLAR 1 DE AGOSTO AL 31 DE DICIEMBRE 2022</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col form-group" id="eva_depe"></div>
                    </div> </form>
```

fragmento de JAVASCRIPT se encuentra en el mismo archivo /seccion/evaluados.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    recargarlista();

    $('#eva_ciclo').change(function() {
        recargarlista();
    });
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recargarlista() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./selects/dependencias_evasel.php",
        data: "ciclo=" + $('#eva_ciclo').val(),
        success: function(r) {
            $('#eva_depe').html(r);
        }
    })
}
```

fragmento código PHP en /seccion/selects/dependencias_evasel.php

```
<?php require '../../config/bd.php';

$ciclo = $_POST['ciclo'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM view_dependencia_cicloesc WHERE id_ciclo='$ciclo'  ";
$result = pg_query($conn,$sql);
$cadena="<label> Dependencia </label>
                    <select class='form-control' id='eva_depe' name='eva_depe'>
                        <option selected> -Elige una dependencia-</option>";
while($ver = pg_fetch_row($result)){
    $cadena=$cadena.'<option value='.$ver[0].'>'.$ver[1].'</option>';   //$ver[0] me arroja clavedepe, $ver[1] el nombre de la dependencia
}
echo $cadena."</select>";?>
```

Lo esperado era que hiciera la inserción normal, sin embargo como lo comenté al principio, duplica las inserciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿no sera un problema de la vista, te fijaste si efectivamente en las tablas estan duplicados los registros?

Comment: Solucionado!, tenías razón... como se establecieron múltiples llaves foráneas(2) al momento de crear las vistas se deben hacer con la condición de ambas se cumplan